# What apn settings to use for mms in Smseagle for AT&T

Tags: att, mms, apn

I use different options from the official AT&T website and I don't get mms with SMSEagle (hardware SMS gateway). I noticed that APN settings are different for android, ios, etc. Which settings to use for "SMSEagle"?

Answer (score 0):

For AT&T MMS settings you should use settings provided in [AT&T knowledlgebase](https://www.att.com/support/article/wireless/KM1062162/)

In short:

APN: NXTGENPHONE

MMSC: http://mmsc.mobile.att.net

MMS proxy: proxy.mobile.att.net

MMS port: 80